Automatically set the computer/taskbar clock constantly (permanently) to a specific set date and time in Windows 10
How to modify the following code in Powershell (with admin privelege) in order to set the computer (taskbar clock/date) to the specified date/time permanently?
$date=[datetime]"30/09/2024 12:00:00";while($true){set-date $date; start-sleep -ms 100}
I'm not corncerned with any side affects on my computer's normal functions.
I have encountered there errors:
First error:
At line:1 char:61 + ... e=[datetime]"30/09/2024 12:00:00";while($true){set-date $date; start- ... + ~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (:) [Set-Date], ParameterBindingValidationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetDateComm and Start-Sleep : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ms'.
Second errror:
At line:1 char:80 + ... 0/09/2024 12:00:00";while($true){set-date $date; start-sleep -ms 100} + ~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Sleep], ParameterBindingException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartSleepCommand Set-Date : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Date' because it is null.

The error message tells you exactly what's wrong - the argument you're passing to Set-Date is $null. Try constructing the initial date instance with Get-Date instead: $date = Get-Date -Day 30 -Month 9 -Year 2024 -Hour 12 -Minute 0 -Second 0 -Millisecond 0

Please format your post properly.


The -ms alias of the -MilliSeconds parameter of the Start-Sleep cmdlet is only available in PowerShell (Core) 7 (the modern, cross-platform, install-on-demand edition), not also in Windows PowerShell (the legacy, ships-with-Windows, Windows-only edition of PowerShell whose latest and last version is 5.1)

Therefore, in code that must (also) run on Windows PowerShell, use the parameter's full name, -MilliSeconds


PowerShell uses the invariant culture in many string operations, which is based on - but not identical to - the US-English culture.

The idea is to provide a predictable scripting experience that isn't affected by what culture happens to be in effect on a given machine. See this answer for background information.

As such, in date formats that do not start with a 4-digit year, only US-style month-first formats are recognized, so your cast would need to put the  month first:

[datetime] '09/30/2024 12:00:00' (represents 30 September 2024 at noon (12 PM))


That said, to avoid potential confusion, you can use an unambiguous yyyy-MM-dd format (along with a 24-hour time-of-day specification, which you already seem to be using):

[datetime] '2024-09-30 12:00:00'






Therefore:
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

$date = [datetime] '2024-09-30 00:00:00'
# CAVEAT: 
#   Setting your computer's clock to an arbitrary point in time can have
#   undesired consequences.
while ($true) { Set-Date $date; Start-Sleep -MilliSeconds 100 }

